# Attributes & Deny Authorizations in NetSqlAzMan

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, azman, netsqlazman

I am using [NetSqlAzMan](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/) for managing authorizations in my application.

In my application, I would like to manage authorization on a record level; allow/deny a user/group to perform an operation on record (e.g. order, customer) #number

I am aware that the solution to such a problem in NetSqlAzMan is using attributes and I have set an small project to test how it works. My application looks like this:

**DBUsers:**

- John
- Bob

**Roles:**

- Admin
- Sales
- Marketing

**Tasks:**

- CreateOrder
- UpdateOrder
- DeleteOrder
- PrintOrder

Authorization examples:

I would like the `Sales` role to be allowed to `UpdateOrder`, but in the same time deny `UpdateOrder` (Attributes: `OrderNum=12`).

I would like to allow `Bob` to `PrintOrder` (Attributes: `OrderNum=13`) and deny `Bob` from `PrintOrder` (Attributes: `OrderNum=16`)

In both cases, I would end up with a `Deny` authorization overriding any allow authorization whether I `CheckedAccess` for `(Sales,UpdateOrder)` or for `(Bob,PrintOrder)`.

Is there any way to get the `AuthorizationType` per attribute or does this require any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetSqlAzMan does not support this and it is not easy to modify it as well.  Here is my discussion with the author.

http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/discussions/282501